# iPad webApps on screen keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I have an HTML web-app which runs in a viewport. The web-app does not scroll. It is all contained within one screen.
I added a text-field  into my app. When I press the input field the on-screen keyboard pops up.
1. The keyboard pushes the web-app upwards for some reason (The view-port defines a resolution which should not allow scrolling).
2. When I am done the app stays "scrolled" off-screen.

Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to control the keyboard using Javascript/CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crude, but can you handle the `blur` event on the form field then call `window.scrollTo(0,0)`?